# Aquamacs and g-client errors

Tags: emacs, google-docs, org-mode, aquamacs, emacspeak

I have installed the g-client library from the [emacspeak google code repository](http://code.google.com/p/emacspeak/source/browse/#svn/trunk/lisp/g-client) and successfully linked the make to Aquamacs by replacing 'emacs' with the the full path to Aquamacs in the Makefile. The module seems to work fine in some cases and not in others.

1. I can `gdoc-publish-from-html` and `gdoc-publish-from-text` with text and simple html buffers.
2. I cannot `gdoc-publish-from-org`, the *Messages* buffer shows:

> Exporting...
>   HTML export done, pushed to kill ring and clipboard
>   ad-Orig-error: Received 400

I also cannot export the html generated from org-mode  unless I remove the following from the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

I am becoming suspicious bout the compatibility of OrgMode html and google docs.

Further, Vivek Haldar [suggests](http://blog.vivekhaldar.com/post/1649745633/editing-google-docs-in-emacs) that one should be able to grab html or text from an existing google doc using `gdocs-fetch-document-html` or `text`. Upon passing the document ID at the prompt, nothing happens, though I am expecting a `*g scratch*` buffer to open containing the content from the document. I suspect that there are two issues afoot here; one being org-mode html--google doc compatibility and the other being an aquamacs specific issue with the g-client lisp code.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, I have backed off on trying to work with google docs in org-mode. Seemed not quite functional....unfortunately.